# Failover hotspot internet won't switch back to Ethernet once it's back

Tags: networking, ethernet, hotspot, failover

I have Gigabit cable internet which is generally stable, but drops out on me maybe a couple times per year, and my work requires no significant/lengthy internet disruptions.  When this happens I want to failover to my Wifi hotspot over 4g.  This works fine by setting Ethernet to Metric 1, and hotspot to Metric 2.

While testing it if I pull the Ethernet, the failover works fine, but when I plug Ethernet back in, the Windows 10 PC will not recognize that Ethernet is back, and switch back.  It stays on the hotspot, consuming my data plan.

Why is this happening and is there a way to make sure Ethernet resumes usage as soon as it comes back?